# how to create versions of Google Forms so we can do dev/test without breaking production?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Is there a way to create versions of a Google Form so we can do development work, like adding new questions, without breaking the production form? Then, when we're ready, a way to push the changes to production.

I know we can make a copy of the form but then we have to manually update it with the changes we want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can source-control the script associated with your form (via [GAS Github Assistant](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-apps-script-github/lfjcgcmkmjjlieihflfhjopckgpelofo?hl=en) or [Clasp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp))  but there is no built-in/out-of-box method that you can easily apply to the form itself.

You can try setting up a custom build process where you have two versions of the form, one for testing and the other for production and then write a script to automate updating the production version of the form, from the test version.

O̶r̶ ̶a̶l̶t̶e̶r̶n̶a̶t̶i̶v̶e̶l̶y̶,̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶C̶l̶a̶s̶p̶ ̶C̶L̶I̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶p̶u̶s̶h̶ ̶c̶h̶a̶n̶g̶e̶s̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶d̶u̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶v̶e̶r̶s̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶s̶i̶m̶i̶l̶a̶r̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶h̶o̶w̶ ̶G̶I̶T̶ ̶b̶r̶a̶n̶c̶h̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶w̶o̶r̶k̶s̶.̶
Striked out that last bit since Clasp CLI only applies to code; you'll need a separate script to migrate the structure of the form between the test and production versions.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into how to use Clasp CLI as I have never used it before. I like the idea of a custom build process to copy a form from dev to prod but I feel like the easiest way would be to remove all the questions from the prod one and add the ones from dev. I need to check how that messes up existing form responses.